# Plotting a bar graph in django using matplotlib

Tags: python, django, matplotlib

I want a bar graph of expense vs date in my django webapp using matplotlib.

There can be multiple entries of expense for a single date. The html page shows 'barcontainer object of 2 artists' . How to solve this question.

Comment: Can you provide your code, please?

Answer (score 0):

You have to convert your chart into string:

```
import io
import base64
import urllib.parse

def myview(request):
    # here create your chart with matplotlib
    ...

    # now export your image as base64 (inline)
    fig = plt.gcf()
    buf = io.BytesIO()
    fig.savefig(buf, format='png')
    buf.seek(0)
    data = urllib.parse.quote(base64.b64encode(buf.read()))

    # return your view here
    return render(..., {'data': data})
```

In your template use something like:

```
<img src="data:image/png;base64,{{ data }}">
```